# OpenGL 2D Game Texture Artifacts

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm drawing supposedly a pixel-perfect game for iOS:

[image]

The problem is that every few frames I see random pieces of another texture being drawn (the teal dots floating in the blackness).  First, I tried making sure the quads all lined up completely.  Next, I changed the Z-buffer size.  Neither of these things seemed to help.

I am using a texture atlas, but unfortunately I can't add in padding pixels (one solution I've seen).  Now, if I change the texture coordinates from 0,1 to 0.005,0.95 the problem goes away but it looks like garbage.

Does the behavior of this screenshot suggest another solution I haven't tied?  Note that my filtering mode has to stay NEAREST for the sprite art, and that the problem goes away when I force my character/camera to move in whole pixel increments (which unfortunately doesn't feel as good as moving in subpixels).

EDIT: I've also tried sampling the "middle" of the texel rather than the boundary by computing my uvs like this:

```
u = (pixelCoordX + 0.5) / pixelsInTexture
v = (pixelCoordY + 0.5) / pixelsInTexture
```

but now everything looks busted.

EDIT: Even if I can't figure out how to fix this, I'd like to understand why it occurs with fractional pixel coordinates and not whole pixel coordinates.  The game isn't zooming, it's only panning so no matter how fractionally I offset a textured tile it seems like it would be the same width -- light up the same amount of pixels -- and not perform this bizarre wrapping.

EDIT: After reading about how texel sampling works, I sort of understand why the non-integer position of all my quads is affecting texturing... but I can't find a definitive doc saying that the OpenGL is "allowed" to use uv coordinates outside of the range specified in my draw call (which is well less than [0,1] as I'm using a texture atlas).

Comment: If the problem goes away when you use those texture coordinates then it's probably related to sampling outside the proper range of texel centers. I would suggest `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`

Comment: Ah, I am using GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, I neglected to mention that.

Comment: Also, don't do that (adjust for texel centers). In OpenGL and D3D10 pixel coordinates (assuming you mean `gl_FragCoord`?) are already aligned to texel centers.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ah, that explains why it looked like pixel stew!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but given what you have posted it seems very likely padding pixels would solve your problem. Why can't you add them?

Comment: Actually @AndonM.Coleman I'm in ES1.1, would that change the situation?

Comment: @racarate: No, OpenGL has always had pixel coordinates aligned with texel coordinates since its inception. It was Direct3D that was the odd-ball prior to D3D10 :)

Comment: Got it, although I feel like an oddball for having problems recreating something Eugene Jarvis did 30 years ago!  :0

Comment: by the way, i did end up just padding my atlas to "solve" this problem!

Comment: and there are some good comments by the powerVR folk about this problem here: http://forum.imgtec.com/discussion/3028/trying-to-understand-texture-atlas-artifacts-on-sgx

Answer (score 2):

Manually doing texture atlases is difficult to get right! I've run into the same issue. If all your textures are square in your texture atlas this may help:

Coordinates on the texture atlas run from 0.0-.1.0f. I have had more success thinking 0.0-0.9999f

In my case, I use 16x16 pixel squares in a texture that is 256x256 pixels, that gives me 16 rows and columns. 1/16 = 0.0625. The first texture coordinate will begin at 0.0 and end before the next texture begins, so: **0.0624**. Texture two begins at 0.0625 and ends at 0.1249 and so on. Doing this has removed those little specks from the next texture.

[Visual Aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zemi4.jpg)

My texture maping looks like:

```
//texture 1
{{0.0624f, 0.9376f},
{0.0624f, 0.9999f},
{0.0f, 0.9999f},
{0.0f, 0.9376f}},

//texture 2
{{0.1249f, 0.9376f},
{0.1249f, 0.9999f},
{0.0625f, 0.9999f},
{0.0625f, 0.9376f}}
```

Also, make sure you're using:

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
```